# WP: Change footer.php from within loop

Tags: php, wordpress

This question is about wordpress.
I have a custom meta in my post.
I need to be able to change my footer (add specific logos - s) depending on which meta tag is present in post. 
The logic is clear to me.

The question is how to reach footer.php within the loop. Or i need to make another in footer.php ? 
The problem I can not deal with footer content through JS because footer is not present on page when loop is happening.

Comment: you can check custom meta by php code in footer file and provide condition to display which footer you have to display according to custom post meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull the meta from anywhere in your theme; even outside the loop. Header, footer, etc. Simply pass `get_the_ID()` as the first parameter of `get_post_meta()`.

`get_the_ID()` retrieves the ID of the post/page being viewed.

Example:

```
<?php $logo_meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'metaFieldName', true ); ?>

<?php if ($logo_meta) echo $logo_meta; ?>
```

To make it simpler:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'myMetaFieldName', true ); ?>
```

Or assuming you were storing only the src of the logo image (URL) as the meta value, something like this would do the trick:

```
<?php
$logo_image_src = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'myMetaFieldName', true );
if ($logo_image_src)
    echo '<img src="'.$logo_image_src.'" alt="theLogoAltTag" />;
?>
```

Also, depending on whether the item was uploaded via the WP Media Library, you could just store the ID of the media item in the post meta and retrieve the image src via `wp_get_attachment_image_src()`.

Comment: Thank you a lot ! I thought get_the_ID() works only inside loop, as written in documentation! Logic is another but thanks for the function! This was what i looking for. I didnt quite get the idea how can it return id, if the page has already benn built. I suppose this is because get_footer is a function. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID

Comment: @Kim Ris No problem! =) It's my understanding that the entire page is within the main loop. If you have multiple loops within the main loop using `get_posts()` or `WP_Query()`, each loop should be reset afterwards to restore the original; thus leaving the original page data available for use later (in the footer).